On the number of invariant Sylow subgroups under coprime action - Antonio Beltrán and Changguo Shao article
This is an article that Antonio Beltrán and Changguo Shao wrote. Lemma 2.5. states: [All groups are supposed to be finite (this is mentioned before)]
Lemma 2.5. Let $A$ be a group acting coprimely on a solvable group $G$ and let $M$ be an $A$-invariant subgroup of $G$. Let $P$ be an $A$-invariant Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ with $P\leq M$, then $\nu^A_p(M)$ divides $\nu^A_p(G)$.
Where $\nu^A_p(G)$ denotes the number of $A$-invariant Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$.
And the beginning of the proof goes like this:
"(...) Let $N$ be a maximal $A$-invariant normal subgroup of $G$. It is clear that $G/N$ is $A$-invariant too and has no nontrivial $A$-invariant proper normal subgroup (I understand this part). Therefore, we can write $G/N = S_1\times\cdots\times S_r$, where $S_i$ are isomorphic simple groups. As $G$ is solvable, then every $S_i$ has prime order, that is, $G/N$ is an elementary abelian subgroup of prime power order. (...)"
I do not understand the part where $G/N$ can be written as a product of isomorphic simple groups.
I know a theorem which states that: If $N$ is a minimal normal subgroup of a group $G$, $A$ is a minimal normal subgroup of $N$, and the set $\{A^g\;|\;g\in G\}$ is finite then, $N$ is isomorph to a direct product of isomorphic simple groups. I have tried to modify the proof of this theorem to solve the problem I have, but I am unable to find an answer.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869317303988
